# Create a dynamic growing pyramid

Tags: javascript, css, interview-questions, html5

In connection with a job application I have to progress the following task:

> Create a dynamic growing pyramid. The structure has to be sorted
>   alphabetically (concerning the inserted values).
>        It has to have the following controls:
>
> - Textbox for inserting texts (used by the blocks of the pyramid).
> - Button which adds the text to the list. Furthermore updates the pyramid.
> - Button which removes the last block of the pyramid. Furthermore updates the pyramid.
>
> You are allowed to use HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Here are screenshots for to demonstrate how it is meant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here the code I've written:

```js
(function() {
  var items = [];
  var addNewItem = document.querySelector('#add-new-item');
  var removeLastItem = document.querySelector('#remove-last-item');
  var textbox = document.querySelector('#content-new-item');
  var pyramidPanel = document.querySelector('#pyramid-panel');
  var colors = ['orange', 'blue', 'red', 'green'];

  function updateItems() {
    var textboxContent = textbox.value

    if (items.length < 5 && textboxContent.length) {
      textbox.value = '';

      items.push({
        textboxContent,
        color: ''
      });

      items.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.textboxContent > b.textboxContent) {
          return 1;
        } else if (a.textboxContent < b.textboxContent) {
          return -1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });

      setColors();
    }
  }

  function setColors() {
    items.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.color = colors[index % colors.length];
    });
  }

  function updateView() {
    items.forEach((item, index) => {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      let span = document.createElement('span');
      let textNode = document.createTextNode(item.textboxContent);

      div.setAttribute('class', 'pyramid-item');
      span.setAttribute('class', 'pyramid-content');

      div.style.borderRight = '75px solid transparent';
      div.style.borderBottom = `50px solid ${item.color}`;
      div.style.borderLeft = '75px solid transparent';
      div.style.marginLeft = ((4 - index) * 75) + 'px';
      div.style.width = (150 * index) + 'px';

      span.appendChild(textNode);
      div.appendChild(span);

      pyramidPanel.appendChild(div);
    });
  }

  function emptyPanel() {
    while (pyramidPanel.firstChild) {
      pyramidPanel.removeChild(pyramidPanel.lastChild);
    }
  }

  addNewItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    updateItems();
    emptyPanel();
    updateView();
  });

  removeLastItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    items.pop();
    emptyPanel();
    updateView();
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

.pyramid-wrap {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 750px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content-new-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}

.nav-item *:nth-child(n + 1) {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.pyramid-item {
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.pyramid-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 70%);
  font-weight: 800;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.nav-item-control:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #555;
  color: #555;
}

button.nav-item-control:hover {
  background-color: #787878;
  color: #eee;
  border: 0;
}

input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #dedede;
}

input:hover::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #dedede;
}

input:hover:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #dedede;
}

button.nav-item-control:active {
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid-wrap">
  <div id="pyramid-panel"></div>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-item">
      <input class="nav-item-control" type="text" id="content-new-item" placeholder="Please enter the text content for next pyramid item ..." />
      <button class="nav-item-control" id="add-new-item">Add new pyramid item</button>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="nav-item-control" id="remove-last-item">Remove last pyramid item</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

What do you think about my idea of computing the margins and widths of each div?

An alternative would have been to write multiple CSS-classes and then adding the corresponding CSS-class.

Which approach is better and for what reason? Are there points which could be improved? Or done better some different way?

Comment: Is the pyramid definitely limited to 5 levels? Must the result be responsive? Is the layout and the HTML markup part of the task or free to chose?

Comment: Beside the task description (received via mail on Friday afternoon) I had three screenshots similar to the ones I published in my question. So I started on Sunday morning and based my HTML / layout upon that. Also I choose to limit my implementation to five levels because of the screenshots. It is demonstrated with five elements there. Responsiveness isn't mentioned in the requirements. So I decided to implement only the mentioned points and to supply as early as possible. Beside that: I will have an exam by the end of this week. So I liked to get it done for becoming my head free.

Comment: But anyway: Many thanks for your answer. Awesome stuff to think about. I they don't call me back again then I have definitely learned a few things.

Comment: If I would ask this task as part of an interview for a frontend developer, these are the things I would look for: "*Can the applicant create a prototype from a vague customer request?*" "*Does the applicant see limitations and edge cases?*" "*Is the source readable and maintainable?* *How are DOM operations handled?*" "*Is the markup semantic?*". However, be careful assuming that mockups show you all use cases or limitations of an application. I would probably add unclear things as questions, like: "*Is this limited to 5 elements?*" or "*Are you sure you want to sort numbers alphabetically?*".

Comment: Valuable thoughts to consider. Thanks a bunch for your advice. :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure what is 'the _last_ block' here? The top-most, the bottom-most or the most recently added one?

Comment: @CiaPan Yep. The description is not very precise. Perhaps on purpose? For to see one handles unclear task descriptions? To me the bottom-most seemed the most likely one. So I've chosen that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few thoughts on the task and your solution:

#### Limited to 5 elements

You're limiting the pyramid to 5 elements. The task doesn't have a restriction like that. I see two possibilities here:

- Do not limit your solution.
- Improve the UX of your solution and explain, why you have a limit included.

When one reaches the maximum, your program seems broken. There's no message explaining, that I can't add more items and why. Also disabling the form elements would be helpful, when going with the restriction.

#### Empty input

I can't add "empty" items. But I *can* add items containing whitespaces only, like `"  "`. [Be more strict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031143/1456376):

```
if (/\S/.test(textboxContent)) {}
```

or allow an empty input as well. However, a message explaining *why* I can't add an item would be nice.

#### Sorting

The task says, *sort alphabetically*. It doesn't say anything about case sensitivity but your solution sorts like this:

1. *aB*
2. *aa*

If this is not desired, use `toLowerCase()` or `.localeCompare()`, like:

```
return a.textboxContent.localeCompare(b.textboxContent);
```

Numbers are sorted [*lexicographic/alphabetically*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127639) already. So `10` comes before `2` and fulfills the task.

#### Styles

I would recommend to decouple the style/CSS from the JavaScript as much as possible. Especially when you handle only 5 items. You don't even need to handle specific classes for each item in JavaScript. Use the [`nth-child()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to style each tile:

```
.pyramid-item:nth-child(1) { color: orange; }
.pyramid-item:nth-child(2) { color: green; }
```

Which will simplify the next part:

#### Update View

`updateView` is doing a lot of things, over and over.

1. If you set all styles in CSS you can get rid of all the calculation.
2. Don't create the same DOM elements again and again. Create them once and store them along with your item:

---

```
let pyramidElement = document.createElement('div');
[…]

items.push({
    content: textboxContent,
    element: pyramidElement
});
```

---

3. Don't call `pyramidPanel.appendChild()` on each iteration. Create a [`DocumentFragment`](https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g/why-you-should-always-append-dom-elements-using-documentfragments), because:

> it […] keeps the recalculation, painting and layout to a minimum.

Finally, your method could be reduced to this:

```
function updateView() {
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    items.forEach((item, index) => {
        fragment.appendChild(item.element);
    }

    pyramidPanel.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

See als [*Should I use document.createDocumentFragment or document.createElement*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3397161/1456376) for more details.

#### RemoveLastItem

Why are you re-creating the whole thing, when you remove the last item? Simply remove that specific element and you're done, like:

```
let item = items.pop();
pyramidPanel.removeChild(item.element);
```

#### Selectors

All selectors use an `id` to address elements. You are using `document.querySelector`, which does the job. But using the explicit selector for this task `document.getElementById` will improve performance, as it is *60%* (Chrome), *70%* (Safari) or *99%* (Firefox) faster. [Test it yourself](https://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementbyid/35).

#### Markup

**`nav` vs. `form`**

From w3.org: "[HTML/Elements/nav](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav)":

> The  element represents a section with navigation links.

Your `nav`-element clearly is not such a section. Also you're using form elements outside a form without linking them to one. So instead of `nav` use a `form`-element.

Keep in mind, that you have to suppress the form submission.

**`button`**

A button without a specified type is a submit button by default. Spend them the `type`-attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="nav-item-control" id="add-new-item">Add new pyramid item</button>
```

**`fieldset`**

As one input and one button act together, you could group them as a `fieldset`:

```
<fieldset class="nav-item">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="button">Add new pyramid item</button>
</fieldset>
```

#### Variable Naming

Try to use descriptive variable names all the time, not only sometimes. `pyramidPanel` is good. But `div` isn't, instead use:

```
let pyramidElement = document.createElement('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

A more modern approach is to utilize a javascript framework.

I have written this similar feature in React which you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/qz98rxy8ow